# Does the Asus Transformer Prime GPS extension kit have a USB pass thru to charge the tablet

Tags: charging, asus-eee-pad-transformer, external-gps

As noted Asus is offering a [GPS Extension Kit for the Asus Tranformer Prime TF201](http://event.asus.com/ASUSPad/TF201GPS/).  Does the module has a pass thru USB multipin connector to allow charging from the USB cable or does one have to remove the module to charge the tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not have any kind of pass through. You cannot charge or dock the Prime when the GPS dongle is plugged in.

[Here's a YouTube unboxing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHnMzlPMC1I) that provides a good overview of its physical design.